# Adding UITextField’s input into an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a simple app that has 3 text fields, a label and a button. User would enter text into the 3 text fields and then press the button. The text from one of the text fields would randomly be selected and applied as the text to a label.

I’ve tried using something like

```
let textArray : String [text1, text2, text3]
```

For the array but this doesn’t seem to be working. Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Share your full code and what exact result do you want?

Comment: set tag for textfields and use the dictionary with textfield tag as a key and text as value

Comment: @Zakth what i think you want to do is -: after pressing button, saving all 3 text filed values in array of type string. Then randomly select value from any index and display on label .

Comment: var randomDecideIndex : Int = 0
    
    var decideArray : String = "decideOption1.input, decideOption2.input, decideOption3.input"
  

   
    
    func randomDecide(){
        randomDecideIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
        decideAnswer.text = String(decideArray)

Comment: @Zakth please edit your question with more information, and removing it from comments.

Comment: @Zakth this -: var decideArray : String = "decideOption1.input, decideOption2.input, decideOption3.input" is not array, its just one long string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take an array and add textfield text into that array.

```
var textFieldArray: [String] {
  return [textfield1.text!, textfield2.text!, textfield3.text!]
}
```

Then generate a random number using the code below:

```
func RandomInt(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
  if max < min { return min }
  return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((max - min) + 1))) + min
}
```

Now get the random text using the index path of the array.

```
let randomNumber = RandomInt(min: 1, max: 3)
let randomText = textFieldArray[randomNumber]
labelName.text = randomText
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was wanting it to do. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I now understand that when using multiple text in a variable I need to use an if statement combined with a constant with a return.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand. You probably want this:

```
var textArray: [String] {
    return [textfield1.text, textfield2.text, textfield3.text]
}
```